# Python Construct a list from gtkEntry

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

Im using gtk2x, python 2.7.3 and I need to make a list from values entered in one of the gtkEntry textboxes. Is there any "simple" way to go around this?

Global variable def:

```
groupID = []
```

Definition of the gtkEntry box:

```
      <object class="GtkEntry" id="gtkENTRY1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">True</property>
        <property name="invisible_char">●</property>
        <property name="text" translatable="yes">-</property>
        <property name="primary_icon_activatable">False</property>
        <property name="secondary_icon_activatable">False</property>
        <property name="primary_icon_sensitive">True</property>
        <property name="secondary_icon_sensitive">True</property>
      </object>
```

Getting object:

```
self.gID = builder.get_object("gtkENTRY1")
```

Getting text from the object:

```
groupID = self.gID.get_text()
```

Values entered:

```
value1,value2
```

Needed output:

```
list = [value1,value2]
```

Actual output:

```
list = [v,a,l,u,e,1,v,a,l,u,e,2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If somebody would like to know and for future reference, I allready solved this by RE split. Something like this:

```
list = re.split(r"\s*[,;]\s*", groupID.strip())
```